# SUBQUERIES with UNION

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables:

```
TICKERS
id 
ticker (varchar 100)

COEF
id
id_ticker
id_spre
coef (varchar 100)

SPRE
id
id_check
name (varchar 100)
```

I need to retrive all the SPRE's records that have id_check = 1 AND then for this result I have to get all the records that have SPRE.id = COEF.id_spre (ONE time) and then all the TICKERS related to the COEF (tickers.id = COEF.id_ticker).

The result shoud be:

```
SPRE.name
COEF.coef
TICKERS.ticker
TICKERS.ticker
TICKERS.ticker
....
....
SPRE.name
COEF.coef
TICKERS.ticker
TICKERS.ticker
TICKERS.ticker
```

(I have repeated `tickers` because many tickers should have the same `COEF`)

I thougth something like:

A query that retrieve all the SPRE with `id_check = 1` and then a SUBQUERY that **UNION** two selects, the FIRST to get the `COEF.id_spre = SPRE.id` and the second to get all the tickers with `TICKERS.id = COEF.id_ticker`

.... but how to write it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wait.. are you wanting to pivot out the results? as in do you want all the tickers related to one spre returned in the same row?

anyway as it stands it looks like something like the following may be of use:

```
SELECT 
    s.name
    ,c.coef
    ,t.ticker
FROM spre  as s 
    INNER JOIN coef as c 
        ON c.id_spre = s.id
    INNER JOIN tickers AS t
            ON t.id = c.id_ticker
    WHERE s.id_check= 1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c984a/15

if you need to limit it for SPREs then would the following work:

```
SELECT 
    s.name
    ,c.coef
    ,t.ticker
FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM spre WHERE id_check=1 LIMIT 0,5 ) as s 
    INNER JOIN coef as c 
        ON c.id_spre = s.id
    INNER JOIN tickers AS t
        ON t.id = c.id_ticker
```

using MSSQL syntax: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c984a/25

Comment: I don't have MySQL here to test but I guess this would work to limit your results by spre

Comment: this query works perfectly! but what about LIMIT ? example: if i need to show the first 5 spread that have id_check = 1, how can I do it? if i add LIMIT 1,5 at the end of your query it surelly truncate the list of the results, (i do not know how many coef a spre has) if if i LIMIT it with a fixed number it should truncate a spre list... do you understand?

Comment: by applying the limit inside that select and then joining to it you are only going to get 5 spres but as many coefs and tickets as there are associated with the 5 spres

Answer (score 1):

No, you should do this in one query using `JOIN` like this:

```
SELECT s.name AS 'SPRE Name', c.coef, t.ticker
FROM SPRE s
INNER JOIN COEF c ON s.id = c.id_spre
INNER JOIN TICKERS t ON c.id_ticker = t.id
WHERE s_id_check = 1
```

The data coming form this query is a tabular data, in the following form:

```
 SPRE NAME |   COEF   |  TICKER
-----------+----------+-----------
  spre1        coef1     ticker11
  sper1        coef1     ticker12
  sper1        coef2     ticker121
  spre2        coef12    ticker22
  ...
```

Then in your application you can output these data the way you want.
**Edit:** If you want to limit the selection of `COEF`s you `LIMIT` them in the joined table:

```
INNER JOIN
( 
   SELECT * FROM COEF LIMIT 0, n
) c ON s.id = c.id_spre
```

**Or:** you can use `WHERE c.id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` if there is no much values.

Comment: If you for some reason need all on same row, you can `GROUP BY s.name` and `GROUP CONCAT(t.ticker)`

Comment: @RobinCastlin, Sure you can, but the OP doesn't want that, see how the sample the results that he wants how it look like. He wants to get a list of tickers for each `COEF` and `SPER`, not to concatanate them in the same row.

Comment: @MGA Here the problem should be if i need to LIMIT the results, example: (how can I get the first 5 SPRE that have id_check = 1) in this case the query has all the records I can't trucate the list without know WHERE a "spre" block finish because it can have different number of coefs

Comment: @Dail, you can limit your query using `LIMIT` or if it is just couple of values you can use: `WHERE c.id in (1, 2, 3, 4)`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem description doesn't need a sql Union. A union is to merge two selects together and returning them as one select for example when you need a pagebrowser.  I suggest to just use a Left Join to concatenate the results for example:

```
        Select * from t1 Left Join t2 ON id_t1 = id_t2 Left Join t3 ON id_t2 = id_t3 Where check_t1 = 1.
```

A Join it also useful when you want to create a tree and read adjaceny lists and avoid a recursive function. In a Left Join empty results not meeting your requirement of the left table are discarded in the result.